# Error while executing sql script!

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am defining a variable in "userdata.sql",its contents are

```
SET DEFINE ON;
DEFINE name = Gaurav
DEFINE today =10/10/2011 --variable that contain date value.
```

==================================================================================

I am creating another file called xyz.sql

```
@userdata.sql
DECLARE 
v_date DATE;
v_name varchar2(10);
BEGIN
v_date:='&today';
v_name:='&name';
dbms_output.put_line('name is '||v_name);
dbms_output.put_line('date is '||v_date);
end;
```

On execution of xyz.sql its throwing an error 
ora-01840 input value not long enough for date format.
Please suggest the solution to it.
The RDBMS i am using is ORACLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
v_date:='&today';
```

to:

```
v_date:=to_date('&today','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

i.e. specify the date format (it could be 'MM/DD/YYYY' instead).